# Transfer some phrase betweeen character in folder names

Tags: linux

I require a little help from you, I need to rename some folders that I have. The problem is that I need to move a part of the folder name and leave it at the beginning, like for example this:

Original:

```
1982-11-03 - Seibu Stadium, Saitama, Japan [FLAC]Space Boogie [version 2][Wardour][AUD][109.56][560.72MB]
```

Required:

```
1982-11-03 - Space Boogie - Seibu Stadium, Saitama, Japan [FLAC][version 2][Wardour][AUD][109.56][560.72MB]
```

So I need to move for example "Space Boogie" phrase into final date, the same way that example.
I know that is difficult but i've tried to make it using sed or anything and no good results

Comment: Use the `rename` command. It allows you to use regular expression matching and replacement.

Comment: Ok, the trick in this case is that the name to transfer is between the first "]" and the first "["

Comment: The following regular expression replacement: `s/- ([^]]*\])([^[]*)/- $2$1/`

Comment: Are there any way to use awk or sed instead rename to get the modified name using the regular expression?

Comment: Yes, but using a tool that's designed for it is easier.

Comment: And how can I assing the modified name into a variable? I need it for a script that I have for rename some folder

Comment: `new_name=(echo "$old_name" | sed '...')`

Comment: I know that but I need to assing the modified name obtanied from rename and assing the the new name into a variable

Comment: There's nothing about that in the question, it just says it needs to rename all the files.

Comment: After you do that assignment, you do `mv "$old_name" "$new_name"`

Comment: And you have the new name in a variable.